# integrability imply continuity??

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $Q \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. let $f: Q \to \mathbb{R}$ be riemann-integrable on $Q$ and suppose $f(x) > 0 $ for all $x \in Q $.

Question: Does it follow that $f$ is continuous on $Q$ ?

Comment: No.${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, $f$ can have discontinuities. For example, a function in one dimension with a finite number of jump discontinuities is integrable. More generally, functions whose discontinuities cover "zero area" are generally integrable - I don't remember the exact hypotheses, but continuity is certainly not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a function equal to $1$ and set it equal to $1/2$ at finitely many points, and the integral will still equal the integral of $f = 1$ so the function is integrable even though it's discontinuous at many points.